# Haskell: Filter applied to too many arguments

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get the index of a value in a list, doing so like this:

```
items = "Test"
zipItems xs = zip xs [0..]
thisItemNumber item = snd . head . filter (\(i, _) -> i == item) (zipItems items)
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `a -> [(a0, c)]'
              with actual type `[(Char, Integer)]'
* Possible cause: `filter' is applied to too many arguments
  In the second argument of `(.)', namely
    `filter (\ (i, _) -> i == item) (zipItems items)'
  In the second argument of `(.)', namely
    `head . filter (\ (i, _) -> i == item) (zipItems items)'
  In the expression:
    snd . head . filter (\ (i, _) -> i == item) (zipItems items)
* Relevant bindings include
    thisItemNumber :: Char -> a -> c (bound at <interactive>:89:5)
```

Which I don't understand. In my mind:

```
zipItems items
```

has type `[(Char, Int)]`

```
\(i, _) -> i == item
```

has type `(Char, a) -> Bool`

and then I'm just applying filter to a type `a -> Bool` and an `a`. How is this going wrong?

Comment: Change it to: 
`thisItemNumber item = snd $ head $ filter (\(i, _) -> i == item) (zipItems items)`
. The problem is that the operator `.` expects a function as parameter, but as you say, `zipItems item` is a list.

Comment: You use the `.` the wrong way here.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks! I could have also put brackets around everything except zipItems.

Comment: Other options: `(snd . head . filter (\(i, _) -> i == item)) (zipItems items)` or `snd . head . filter (\(i, _) -> i == item) $ zipItems items` or `snd . head $ filter (\(i, _) -> i == item) (zipItems items)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `.` there. The `.` operator creates a pipeline of functions:

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

In your case the code is

```
snd . head . filter (\(i, _) -> i == item) (zipItems items)
```

`snd` is a function.

`head` is a function.

But `filter (\(i, _) -> i == item) (zipItems items)` is not a function, it's a list.

That's why you get an error: To be able to use `.`, you must give it a function.

```
* Couldn't match expected type `a -> [(a0, c)]'
              with actual type `[(Char, Integer)]'
```

says `.` expects some kind of function (which must return a list of tuples to satisfy `snd . head`), but what you're actually giving it is a list.

Possible solutions:

- Don't use `.` at all:

  ```
  snd (head (filter (\(i, _) -> i == item) (zipItems items)))
  ```

  All of your functions are fully applied so you don't really need a function pipeline.
- Use `$` instead of parens:

  ```
  snd $ head $ filter (\(i, _) -> i == item) $ zipItems items
  ```

  Deeply nested code can be hard to decipher. We can get rid of `)))` by using `$` instead.
- Build a function pipeline, but immediately apply it to an argument:

  ```
  (snd . head . filter (\(i, _) -> i == item) . zipItems) items
  ```

  Now all operands of `.` are functions, but we take the whole thing and apply it to `items` at the end.

Or you could just use the standard library and do

```
import Data.List

thisItemNumber item = elemIndex item items
```

This slightly changes the return type of `thisItemNumber` to `Maybe Int` because it's possible that `item` doesn't appear in `items`. If you want to ignore this error:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

thisItemNumber item = fromJust (elemIndex item items)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to use `elemIndex` because as you say it has a Maybe return type which I've found generally adds nothing to the code except a load of wrappers everywhere. Abusing it with `fromJust` seems OK though.

Answer (score 1):

You somehow wrote a function that looks like a (wrong) mix between the a "function pipeline" (with the `(.)` operator), and an approach where you specify the parameter.

Since you define a chain of functions, you need to put these between brackets if you perform function application with `zipItem items` here, since otherwise the function application only binds with the last item of the chain: the `filter (\(i, _) -> i == item)`. If you write:

```
f . g x
```

then this is interpeted as:

```
f . (g x)
```

But the `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` operator expects that the second operand is a function, where `filter (\(i, _) -> i == item) (zipItems items)` is a `[(Char, Int)]`, so the two do *not* match.

So by adding brackets, we obtain:

```
thisItemNumber :: (Enum c, Num c) => Char -> c
thisItemNumber item = (snd . head . filter (\(i, _) -> i == item)) (zipItems items)
```

Since it is possible that the element can not be found, it might however be useful to use [**`listToMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:listToMaybe) and return a `Maybe c`, such that it is clear that this function can fail to find the element:

```
import Data.Maybe(listToMaybe)

thisItemNumber :: (Enum c, Num c) => Char -> Maybe c
thisItemNumber item = (listToMaybe . map snd . filter ((item ==) . fst)) (zipItems items)
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.Maybe> thisItemNumber 'L'
Nothing
Prelude Data.Maybe> thisItemNumber 'a'
Nothing
Prelude Data.Maybe> thisItemNumber 'T'
Just 0
Prelude Data.Maybe> thisItemNumber 'e'
Just 1
Prelude Data.Maybe> thisItemNumber 'X'
Nothing
```

That being said, what you here aim to do, already exists (well not with this specific values of course), with the [**`elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:elemIndex) function.

So the last function is equivalent to:

```
import Data.List(elemIndex)

thisItemNumber :: (Enum c, Num c) => Char -> Maybe c
thisItemNumber item = elemIndex item items
```

or we can unwrap the value from the `Just` data constructor with [**`fromJust :: Maybe a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromJust):

```
import Data.List(elemIndex)
import Data.Maybe(fromJust)

thisItemNumber :: (Enum c, Num c) => Char -> c
thisItemNumber item = fromJust (elemIndex item items)
```

although, as said before, this means that your function can error, which is typically *not* advisable.